# WebView stop scrolling after applying CSS Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, webview, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

After Desalinization of the Json I got HTML content (). I append Html,head and body tag to this web content in order to apply CSS.

But problem is When I apply CSS and Js, web view is stop scrolling. and my table data is stuck in web view.

Same Html page is not scroll in my simple web browser but it is perfectly work in windows mobile application. It is not working in xamarin forms.

Final HTML I have generate from JSON data. only  content comes from json.

```
<html style="background: #ffffff">
<head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 , maximum-scale=1,  user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href='http://14.141.36.212/maharastracmo/sites/all/themes/maharastracmonew/css/style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<script src="http://192.168.5.123/maharastracmolatest/latest/misc/jquery.js?v=1.4.4"></script>
<script src="http://192.168.5.123/maharastracmolatest/latest/sites/all/themes/maharastracmonew/js/functions.js?obsm2a"></script>
<script src="http://192.168.5.123/maharastracmolatest/latest/sites/all/themes/maharastracmonew/js/general.js?obsm2a"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="bgColorWhite">
<table class="tableData formarTable responsiveTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Name of CM</th>
            <th colspan="2">Duration</th>
            <th>Political Party Belongs to</th>
            <th>No. of Days Served</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Vacant(President's rule)</td>
            <td>09/28/14</td>
            <td>10/31/14</td>
            <td>N/A</td>
            <td>32 days</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Prithviraj Chavan</td>
            <td>11/11/10</td>
            <td>09/26/14</td>
            <td rowspan="6">Indian National Congress</td>
            <td>1415 Days</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">Ashok Chavan</td>
            <td>11/07/09</td>
            <td>11/09/10</td>
            <td>368 Days [Total 679 Days]</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>12/08/08</td>
            <td>10/15/09</td>
            <td>311 Days</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Vilasrao Deshmukh&nbsp;</td>
            <td>11/01/04</td>
            <td>12/04/08</td>
            <td>1494 Days [Total 2681 Days]</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sushilkumar Shinde</td>
            <td>01/18/03</td>
            <td>10/30/04</td>
            <td>651 Days</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Vilasrao Deshmukh</td>
            <td>10/18/99</td>
            <td>01/16/03</td>
            <td>1187 Days</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Narayan Rane</td>
            <td>02/01/99</td>
            <td>10/17/99</td>
            <td rowspan="2">Shiv Sena</td>
            <td>259 Days</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Manohar Joshi</td>
            <td>03/14/95</td>
            <td>01/31/99</td>
            <td>1419 Days</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sharad Pawar&nbsp;</td>
            <td>03/06/93</td>
            <td>03/14/95</td>
            <td rowspan="8">Indian National Congress</td>
            <td>739 Days [Total 2413 Days]</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sudhakarrao Naik</td>
            <td>06/25/91</td>
            <td>02/22/93</td>
            <td>608 Days</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sharad Pawar&nbsp;</td>
            <td>06/26/88</td>
            <td>06/25/91</td>
            <td>1094 Days</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Shankarrao Chavan&nbsp;</td>
            <td>03/12/86</td>
            <td>06/26/88</td>
            <td>837 Days [Total 1623 Days]</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Shivajirao Patil Nilangekar</td>
            <td>06/03/85</td>
            <td>03/06/86</td>
            <td>277 Days</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Vasantdada Patil&nbsp;</td>
            <td>02/02/83</td>
            <td>06/01/85</td>
            <td>851 Days [Total 1304 Days]</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Babasaheb Bhosale</td>
            <td>01/21/82</td>
            <td>02/01/83</td>
            <td>377 Days</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Abdul Rehman Antulay</td>
            <td>06/09/80</td>
            <td>01/12/82</td>
            <td>583 Days</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Vacant (President's rule)</td>
            <td>02/17/80</td>
            <td>06/08/80</td>
            <td>N/A</td>
            <td>113 Days</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sharad Pawar</td>
            <td>07/18/78</td>
            <td>02/17/80</td>
            <td>Progressive Democratic Front</td>
            <td>580 Days</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">Vasantdada Patil</td>
            <td>03/07/78</td>
            <td>07/18/78</td>
            <td rowspan="9">Indian National Congress</td>
            <td>134 Days</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="38">04/17/77</td>
            <td>03/02/78</td>
            <td>319 Days</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Shankarrao Chavan</td>
            <td>02/21/75</td>
            <td>04/16/77</td>
            <td>786 Days</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3">Vasantrao Naik</td>
            <td>03/13/72</td>
            <td>02/20/75</td>
            <td>709 Days [Total 4097 Days]</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>03/01/67</td>
            <td>03/13/72</td>
            <td>1840 Days</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>12/05/63</td>
            <td>03/01/67</td>
            <td>1548 Days</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>P. K. Sawant</td>
            <td>11/25/63</td>
            <td>12/04/63</td>
            <td>10 Days</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Marotrao Kannamwar</td>
            <td sdnum="1033;0;MM/DD/YY" sdval="22970">11/20/62</td>
            <td sdnum="1033;0;MM/DD/YY" sdval="23339">11/24/63</td>
            <td>370 Days</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Yashwantrao Chavan</td>
            <td>05/01/60</td>
            <td>11/19/62</td>
            <td>933 Days</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div></body></html>
```

**I can not figure out what is actual problem and also not understand It's problem of my html or Xamarin.forms or missing property of webView.**

Code is :

```
private async void CallWebService()
        {
            try
            {
                List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
                values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("page_id", "15"));

                var response = await GeneralClass.GetResponse<RootObject>("http://14.141.36.212/maharastracmo/api/getpagecontent", values);
                string webcontent = response.page_content;
                var HTMLString = CreateHTMLForFormerCMs(webcontent);
                var html = new HtmlWebViewSource
                {
                    Html = HTMLString
                };

                web.Source = html;
            }

            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Something goes wrong...", "Detail:" + ex, "Ok");
            }
        }

        private string CreateHTMLForFormerCMs(string webcontent)
        {
            var css = "<link href='http://14.141.36.212/maharastracmo/sites/all/themes/maharastracmonew/css/style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>"
                 + "<script src=\"http://192.168.5.123/maharastracmolatest/latest/misc/jquery.js?v=1.4.4\"></script>"
                  + "<script src=\"http://192.168.5.123/maharastracmolatest/latest/sites/all/themes/maharastracmonew/js/functions.js?obsm2a\"></script>"
            + "<script src=\"http://192.168.5.123/maharastracmolatest/latest/sites/all/themes/maharastracmonew/js/general.js?obsm2a\"></script>";

                var htmlConcat = string.Format("<html style=\"background: #ffffff\"><head> <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1 , maximum-scale=1,  user-scalable=no\" /><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" />{1}</head>" +
                                                      "<body>"
                                                      +
                                                      "<div class=\"bgColorWhite\"><section class=\"content contentarea\">{0}</section></div></body></html>", webcontent, css); 


            return htmlConcat;
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure that the device is able to access each of those IP addresses' files?

Comment: Yes, Its perfectly open in browser

Comment: On Android, look in the Output window or in the Android Device Monitor log and look for any JavaScript console error messages. If you do not see any, you might try adding some `console.log()` messages in your JavaScript code to figure out where it is failing.